# toggleClass display:none wth initial load set to display:none

Tags: jquery, css

I am toggling a selected target with a .fold class, that displays: none.

On window.load , I select the target and addClass('fold'), so that the targets are initially not displayed.

However, then when toggled the display does not stay within its margins specified by the css.

The toggleClass works (obeys the original display rules), if I do not attempt to hide the targets first.

I have also tried to addClass('fold'), and then toggleClass('unfold').  This resulted in toggle not working.

css:

```
.unfold{
display: block;
}
.fold {
    display: none;
}

$(function(){
$('.octothorpe').on({
    click:function(e){     
        e.preventDefault();
        var $pfold = $(this).closest('.octowrap').siblings('p');
        var $cfold = $(this).closest('.docs').siblings('.code');
        var $sector = $(this).closest('.section');
        var $h2 = $sector.nextUntil('.section:has(h2)').slice(0,-1);

        $pfold.toggleClass('fold');   
        $cfold.toggleClass('fold');   
        $h2.toggleClass('fold');

    }});
});

//on page load click all octothorpe
$(window).load( function() {
        var $pfold = $('.octothorpe').closest('.octowrap').siblings('p');
        var $cfold = $('.octothorpe').closest('.docs').siblings('.code');
        var $sector = $('.octothorpe').closest('.section');
        var $h2 = $sector.nextUntil('.section:has(h2)').slice(0,-1);

        $pfold.addClass('fold');        
        $cfold.addClass('fold');        
        $h2.addClass('fold');

});
```

Comment: Why don't you use .hide() and .show() ?

Comment: looked into hide() show(), and found toggle(), but that just messes up the original css that I am trying to extend,the margins get screwed up, ie is this a block vs inline style issue?

Comment: basically why does the first function work, but when I try to default to display:none on window.load does the margins and stuff(original styling) get messed up?  I tried moving the location of the .fold class to the top of the file to give it less specificity, but that did not work either

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle.net?